# Page still reload when 'cancel' button clicked in confirm Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, confirm

I have this weird experience right now. and searching all possible answer and tested it and yet nothing works on my situation. My problem is that I have a confirmation when deleting a data, the `ok` button in `confirm` working perfectly but when I click `cancel` still proceed and reload the page.

Here is my quick code preview:

```
<a href="MY_URL" onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?");'><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, without further information about the surrounding UI and the data service, it is not rally possible to answer this question. One can expect that the cancel button needs to stop some kind of XHR request, or signal the server to stop otherwise. Its not possible to tell what the case is with information provided.

Comment: @Miaplacidus is it possible the cause of this is from to my extended js script files and jQuery?

Comment: not sure but try: onclick='return confirm("Are you sure?");return false'

Comment: @Quarter I already tried that nothing works, its still the same the problem.

Comment: i tried your code and it works fine in chrome, please give more input on what you are trying.

Comment: Same as @jaideep_johny code works fine in chrome; what browser are you using?

Comment: It works from my other project, but on this project when i click the `cancel` it is still reload the page. and also i have a idea it comes from the jquery of the bootstrap? i dont know. if i'm right.

Comment: @KimNicoleSabordo that means this code is working something else is breaking, which requires further info from your end